# Push Notification for BREW OS Handsets?

Tags: push-notification, brew-framework

I know the smartphone providers are now providing **Push Notifications**. I have searched and found **Android, iPhone, Blackberry, WP7, Symbian** are in the list. 
*But I want to know whether I can use Push Notification Technology on **BREW** handsets or not.* 
Any information regarding this question is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - BREW doesn't support anything like that, because BREW isn't designed for it (it's over 10 years old). You could use SMS messages instead.